# How to create Top Bar which does not refresh when page is refreshig with Ajax or?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have created a simple top bar for my new website.
Here is the code for him in css. It's simple div bar.

```
.topbar {
display:block;
width:100%;
height:40px;
background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
```

I want to put in this top bar a simple .SWF flash mp3 player.
And i want to make this bar to not reload or refresh when people are browsing inner website pages on which this top bar exists.

Something like the top bar on http://soundcloud.com

How i can make this bar to not refresh?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.
I don't want to put the rest of the website in iframe. 
Somehow i want to make it with Javascript?

Can someone explain more for this - http://angularjs.org/ It was given me by the answers!

Comment: Iframes are the easiest way, but for sure not the best way

Comment: Look into building a modern single page web application. The design considerations are much broader to explain fully on StackOverflow.

Comment: I didn't think that iframe is a good way to do that. I think you must use single page web application. So you need to use strong Javascript framework to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by not refreshing the entire page but only by refreshing the parts (other than the top bar) using Ajax and Javascript.

You can use easy and strong framework like [`AngularJS`](http://angularjs.org/).

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to put too much effort just use `iframe`, simple.

But if you want a solid approach, I suggest go through below posts

[Stackoverflow Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627069/how-can-i-keep-a-music-player-in-the-page-footer-that-doesnt-reload-when-i-clic)

[Stackoverflow Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334035/footer-with-music-player-inside-which-does-not-refresh-when-i-click-on-another-p)

Answer (score -1):

You could put the rest of the website in an iframe

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe