# Run ajax scripts on page when navigating with ajax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I got a bit of an issue in my ASP.NET MVC project.

I have a chat div in the bottom right corner (like facebook), and of course I do not want this to reload when navigating to all my navigation is ajax.

The problem I am facing is that I use the following code on the top of the view page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#divTS').hide();
    $('a#showTS').click(function() {
 $('#divTS').slideToggle(400);
 return false;
  });
});

</script>
```

The problem is that this code is only loaded with ajax and does not seem to fire? I would like to run all scripts in the newly loaded view, just as if I hadn't navigated with ajax.

I cannot put this in the site.master as it only loads once and then probably the divs I am trying to hide doesn't exist.

**Is there a good way to run scripts in the ajax-loaded div?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to run the scripts in the success callback function of your ajax script. I would recommend you externalizing this into a separate function:

```
function setupEffects() {
    $('#divTS').hide();
    $('a#showTS').click(function() {
        $('#divTS').slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setupEffects();
});
```

And in the success callback of your script call this function:

```
success: function(result) {
    setupEffects();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that all scripts will be run everytime someone navigates, even the scripts which have nothing to do with the current page?

Comment: Organize your scripts into separate methods depending on their function and invoke them when necessary.

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll do it this way :)

Answer (score 0):

The Masterpage gets reloaded when you navigate to another View. You can also check if a div exists with `$('#div').length > 0`.

By the way, "full site" ajax navigation should not be used. Reload your chat on navigation - best put it into a control (makes things easier).

Comment: The whole idea of the ajax navigation is to not reload the master page... Also, the full site ajax navigation is based on some search and it seems to be the best way to do it

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554243/how-are-the-facebook-chat-windows-implemented